# Windows freezes with USB Plug-andPlay sound, showing random external device 6416 events

Tags: windows-10, security

I've been having an odd issue for about 5 months and it will just randomly happen once or twice a day.

Out of the blue I'll get a USB plugin sound and then my video freezes for about 2 minutes and I cannot figure out what was doing it.

Today, I just randomly checked Event Viewer at the exact moment and it happens with an event 6416 A new external device was recognized by the system. I have no idea what's causing it, and not even sure where to look. The 2 devices always are, new generic PNP monitor and high def audio.

I know for a fact these events are occurring when I'm not even logged in or doing anything.

High def audit:

[image]

PNP monitor:

[image]

Log:

[image]

Comment: By the error messages, the device in question seems to be a monitor connected via NVIDIA GPU. If this monitor is having connection troubles, see if the connecting cable is well-seated on both ends, or try another cable (if possible). Please give details on how is the monitor is connected.